# Vuex best practices for complex objects

Tags: vuex

My Vuex store contains objects with a variety of complexity.  Some have nested objects, some have arrays of nest objects.

I could create generic function to mutate a specified property along the lines of:

```
setProperty(state,{ type, id, prop, value })
{
  state[type][id][prop] = value;
}
```

but that will quickly get complicated for nested object, arrays of objects.   It also seems very tedious to have to create a mutation for every single object property, nested or otherwise.

What are the best practices for creating mutations to modify objects, nested objects, arrays, etc?

Another related issue, is it considered bad form to pass the objects into the mutations as opposed to looking them up in the state:

```
setProperty(state,{ obj, prop, value })
{
  obj[prop] = value;
}
```

Comment: Referenced discussion / cross-post:  https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-best-practices-for-complex-objects/10143

Answer (score 9):

Generally speaking, it is best if you just could avoid nested state structure at first place. I'm not sure how your data are structured, but if you're doing that because you have relationship between those object or area of object, it might be worth trying normalizing the state shape.

Here is the good article from Redux author. It's talking about Redux but the core concept is very same for the Vuex.
https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

And the [Vues ORM](https://github.com/vuex-orm/vuex-orm) is a library that do that for you automatically.

Comment: That redux js link is sadly decayed.